# How can I make my nav take up full width of parent?

Tags: html, css

I need my navbar to stretch the full width of the page. Setting the navbar's width to 100% adds a small amount of extra space to the right for some reason.

This is my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.primary-header {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  justify-content: center;
}

.primary-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.primary-navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.primary-navigation a:hover,
.primary-navigation a:focus {
  color: #afafaf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="primary-header" class="primary-header flex">
    <nav>
      <ul id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation flex">
        <li><a href="index.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="quals.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I bet it's a really simple fix, but I haven't coded in a while so I'm a bit rusty. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few minor correction to your styling:

1. since nav is the only child in `#primary-header`, the `flex` can be remove
2. `primary-navigation` is having the `flex` display, you can use the `justify-content: center` to centered the menu and remove the `width: 100%`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.primary-header {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  justify-content: center;
}

.primary-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 2px solid red;
  
  justify-content: center;
}

.primary-navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.primary-navigation a:hover,
.primary-navigation a:focus {
  color: #afafaf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="primary-header" class="primary-header">
    <nav>
      <ul id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation flex">
        <li><a href="index.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="quals.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.html">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between full width of the parent div and of your device screen. If you want to make your navbar take full width of your screen implement this code:

```
#primary-header { width: 100vw }
```

and the `vw` means viewport width and you are telling the code to make this div take the full width of the screen.

but if you want to make full width of the parent div use the `%` sign instead of `vw`

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Moreover, make sure you have removed all default margins that are made by your browser by adding this code `*{margin:0}`